# Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider - Bootstrap UI modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with UI Bootstrap modal.

In one controller I have this:

```
app.controller("tableCtrl",['$scope','$http','$uibModal','$log' ,function ($scope, $http,$uibModal,$log) {
  $scope.open = function (size,selectedUser) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller:'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      user: function () {
        return selectedUser;
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

In another I have this:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',['$scope','$uibModalInstance','user', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, user) {
  $scope.user = user;
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };
}]);
```

`myModalContent` looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header"><h1>EDIT</h1></div>
    <div class="modal-body"> 
        {{patient.patient_id}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

I only call `tableCtrl` in HTML and call `open` function like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open('lg',patient)">Edit</button>
```

When I click the edit button I receive this exception:

```
Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance
```

I saw [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/khySg1gJjqz1Qv4g4cS5?p=preview) but it didnt help me.

What is wrong?

Comment: are you including the dependency on the module ? angular.module("yourapp", ["ui.bootstrap", ..] 
Also, what version are you using?+

Comment: Try to change injected name `'$uibModalInstance'` to `'$modalInstance'`

Comment: Yes.   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: Are you sure that you have the latest verison of ui.bootstrap? As i could see, rename of $modalInstante to $uibModalInstance were 2 weeks ago

Comment: Ok. Change name to '$modalInstance' help :) ! Thank You!

Comment: I had the same problem with Ui boostrap version 1.3.2. Put '$uibModalInstance' as the last injection resolved my issue.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, so from my solution here's how you could solve your scenario

```
app.controller("tableCtrl",['$scope','$http','$uibModal','$log' ,function ($scope, $http,$uibModal,$log) {
  $scope.open = function (size,selectedUser) {
  var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller:function($uibModalInstance ,$scope,user){
     $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
         };

    },
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      user: function () {
        return selectedUser;
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Work for me as well

Comment: ah really great. 
real thing is *controller* and it's fun

Comment: An explanation of what's going on, as opposed to just code, would be nice

Answer (score 7):

The Problem Identified is: My Control was reinitializing from HTML Page. Make sure the Modal controller is initalized from one place

Answer (score 3):

I Had the exact same problem. updating both angular and ui-bootstap library fixed my problem. Use bower to update ui-bootstrap, it suggests the version of angular that is working with it. Hope I helped.

Comment: I had same problem with `angular-bootstrap`'s `0.14.1` version. I updated to `0.14.3` and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I found that this problem occurred when I defined the controller in the template HTML rather than in the modal.open call

Answer (score 1):

Having the controller function, inline and inside the uibModalInstance object definition was causing me the same issue.

After upgrading to 0.14.3, when the javascript was uglified, uibModalInstance was throwing unknown provider. Defining the controller using 'app.controller', fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of angular-ui/boostrap have different injecter variable names.

Check out [angular-ui/bootstrap example.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs)