# $uibModal - dismiss failing to invoke

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I know there are numerous threads on this issue, but I have tried to follow solutions provided but am having no success.

The one I followed which resolved the error `Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider`, was the answer from @GeorgeKach in [Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider - Bootstrap UI modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455271/unknown-provider-uibmodalinstanceprovider-bootstrap-ui-modal). The error has been removed and the modal opens, but my `dismissal/close` methods aren't invoking.

```
    vm.open = function() {

        console.log('open') //invokes

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/modalTemplate.html',
            appendTo: undefined,
            controller: function($uibModalInstance ,$scope){

                vm.ok = function () {
                    console.log('ok') //fails
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                };

                vm.cancel = function () {
                    console.log('close') //fails
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };

            }
        })

        modalInstance.result.then(function() {
          //resolved
        }, function() {
          //rejected
        })
    }
```

***Question***

Why are my `ok` and `cancel` methods not invoking? Rather than providing a work around, can someone explain why they aren't invoking?

**Template**

```
<div class="modal-header d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <i class="fa fa-warning fa-3x"></i>
    <p class="h4 txt-phase-red">Remove Patent</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <p class="font-body">Are you sure you want to remove patent application xxxxxxxxxx?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn--lg font-body font-body--component bg-phase-red txt-white" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">No</button>
    <button class="btn btn--lg font-body font-body--component bg-phase-green txt-white" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Yes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is vm.cancel() being called from?

Comment: Apologies. Edited my question. It is being called within the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should you `controllerAs`, and set it to `vm`

> controllerAs (Type: string, Example: ctrl) - An alternative to the controller-as syntax. Requires the controller option to be provided as well.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/modalTemplate.html',
        appendTo: undefined,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: function($uibModalInstance){

            var vm = this;

            vm.ok = function () {
                console.log('ok') //fails
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            vm.cancel = function () {
                console.log('close') //fails
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

        }
    })
```

Of course you can avoid using these kind of simple controllers by utilizing `$close(result)` and `$dismiss(result)` inside the template

```
<button class="btn btn-lg font-body font-body--component bg-phase-red txt-white" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')">No</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg font-body font-body--component bg-phase-green txt-white" ng-click="$close('ok')">Yes</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for time and advice @svarog. Appreciated

Comment: Yes, u r right. @PatrickMcDermott im going to change my answer. Please accept this one. also +1

Answer (score 1):

For your concept use `$scope` instead `vm` or add attribute `controllerAs`

---

Change `vm` to `$scope`:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    console.log('ok') //fails
     $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

$scope.cancel = function () {
  console.log('close') //fails
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

or:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/modalTemplate.html',
        appendTo: undefined,
        controllerAs: 'vm',  <--- add 
        controller: function($uibModalInstance ,$scope){

            vm.ok = function () {
                console.log('ok') //fails
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            vm.cancel = function () {
                console.log('close') //fails
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

        }
    })
```

Comment: I would save myself time if I actually read the documentation. Thank you for your time @Maxim

Comment: `$uibModal does not support controller as` it actually does